# Where can I find the Javascript file for a page returned by uri?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, uri

In my app, we have a 'sign in' button in Page 1, which will direct to the actual sign in page.

So when it is clicked, it sends a request to the server, and the server returns a uri.

Then the page is rendered. I will call this Page 2.

This page 2 has email, password input fields, and continue button.

Now, I need to figure out where the continue button is sending the POST request to, so I need access to the Javascript file of this page 2 rendered by the uri.

When I goto Sources tab however, I do not see any Javascript files.

All I see is the image below

[image]

Where can I access the file?

I have searched the server repo as well for the frontend code of the uri returned, but could not find.

There is nothing logged in the Networks tab as well, when I enter email, password, and click continue on page 2 to log in.

EDIT:

I have looked at the 'Element tab' for Page 2. This is the html code for the form (email , password, continue button). Note that I changed some attributes to camelCase.

```
 <form
                    method="POST"
                    className="c2d54d3ec c0a5e167e"
                    
                  >
                    <input
                      type="hidden"
                      name="state"
                      value="asdasdasdasdasdaIDELETEDTHIS33322E5yb0g"
                    />

                    <div className="cfb71d41a c9514219f">
                      <div className="cafdaf6cc">
                        <div className="input-wrapper _input-wrapper">
                          <div
                            className="cdaa5633a c2ff41511 text c083604f6 c8c2b35f6"
                            data-action-text=""
                            data-alternate-action-text=""
                          >
                            <label
                              className="c2b602944 no-js cac31896e c7e047387"
                              htmlFor="username"
                            >
                              Email address
                            </label>

                            <input
                              className="input cab61d8c8 c4c289c94"
                              inputMode="email"
                              name="username"
                              id="username"
                              type="text"
                              //   value=""
                              required={true}
                              autoComplete="username"
                              autoCapitalize="none"
                              spellCheck="false"
                              autoFocus={true}
                            />

                            <div
                              className="c2b602944 js-required cac31896e c7e047387"
                              data-dynamic-label-for="username"
                              aria-hidden="true"
                            >
                              Email address
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="input-wrapper _input-wrapper">
                          <div
                            className="cdaa5633a c2ff41511 password cbe83985a c8c2b35f6"
                            data-action-text=""
                            data-alternate-action-text=""
                          >
                            <label
                              className="c2b602944 no-js cac31896e cbef58c3b"
                              htmlFor="password"
                            >
                              Password
                            </label>

                            <input
                              className="input cab61d8c8 cbcf0d22b"
                              name="password"
                              id="password"
                              type="password"
                              required={true}
                              autoComplete="current-password"
                              autoCapitalize="none"
                              spellCheck="false"
                            />

                            <div
                              className="c2b602944 js-required cac31896e cbef58c3b"
                              data-dynamic-label-for="password"
                              aria-hidden="true"
                            >
                              Password
                            </div>

<div className="c31e91fde">
                      <button
                        type="submit"
                        name="action"
                        value="default"
                        className="c55316539 c8538d135 ca2869ec9 c448bcaa9 c9774d53b"
                      >
                        Continue
                      </button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: There's not much we can do to help because you don't show us any of the URLs or page sources.  Browser page javascript can either be in external script files `<script src="xxx"></script>` or it can be in inline `<script>Javascript code here </script>` tags.  And, buttons can also be configured to post a `<form>` without any Javascript (pure HTML).

Comment: @jfriend00 Hello, your comment really help me a lot. I have updated the original post (See EDIT). It has the HTML code for the form, algthough I don't think it provides much useful info. I will look into what you commented just now. Meanwhile, please inform me if the EDIT provided any useful info. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @jfriend00 added the html code for continue button just now.

Comment: There is an awesome feature in chrome dev tools under the network tab that lets you record all requests made by the site. Just load dev tools, switch to the networking tab, and then make sure it's recording. Once you submit the form, check to see if there are any entries that would make sense. Along with the URLs, you can also see request and response bodies. Would this help you?

Comment: To see exactly what the browser is doing when that Continue button is pressed, open up the Inspector in the browser (right click in the page and select "Inspect").  Go to the Network tab.  Load your desired page in the browser.  Clear the network tab by hitting the circle with a slash through it on the top left of the network tab.  Then, click the continue button and watch in the network tab exactly what the browser does.

Comment: Note, the continue button is set up to POST the form automatically without Javascript, except the `<form>` tag has no `action` attribute so there must be some Javascript somewhere that is handling the form post instead.

Comment: FYI, if you give us a live link to this page, we can more thoroughly see what's going on.